# writing a data structure in an algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic, data-structures, algpseudocode

I am trying to write up a data structure in my algorithm.

```
\documentclass[]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Algorithm1}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    *This is where I want my structure to go*    

    code....

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I have seen alternatives such as using:

```
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
```

and defining my own:

```
\SetKwProg{struct}{struct}{ contains}{end}
```

Is there a way to define a structure such that I am still using `algorithmic`?

Another solution I came up with was to use the following:

```
\algnewcommand\algorithmicstruct{\textbf{Structure}}
\algnewcommand\Structure{\item[\algorithmicstruct]}
```

However, this results in the word `Structure` being placed on an unnumbered line. Does anyone know how to use this command such that it becomes part of the remaining code and gets a number as any other line?